# Outlook Web Add-in > Control Menu separator & entry with no icon

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Working with an office Web Add-In, I am trying to:

1. Add a sub menu entry with no icon: When no icon is set a default one is picked up. I can obviously add a transparent pixel picture but that's not really elegant.
2. Add a separator like the menuSeparator in a VSTO add-In.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you developing a COM addin or Web addin?

Comment: Hello, I am working on an office web Add-in.

Comment: This isn't possible. There isn't a way to create a menu separator. All control elements in the manifest, need to have an icon. As you observed, If the icon cannot be downloaded/obtained, then a default icon will be used. Your workaround is currently the only way to accomplish a "no icon" scenario.

Comment: All right. Thanks for your answer.